# TLSharp hangs on during start

Tags: c#, android, telegram

I have a class in my application for working with Telegram. It uses TLSarp library. It has following code for initialization:

```
    public TelegramBridge()
    {
        client = CreateClient();
        InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(client).Wait();
    }

    public TelegramClient CreateClient()
    {
        TelegramClient clt = null;

        clt = new TelegramClient(apiID, apiHash, _sessionStore, "/mnt/sdcard/smsservice/session");

        return clt;
    }

    public async Task<TelegramClient> InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(TelegramClient cli)
    {
        try
        {
            await cli.ConnectAsync();
            if (cli.IsUserAuthorized())
            {
                Logger.Info("User is authorized already");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error("User is not authorized");
                var codeRequest = await cli.SendCodeRequestAsync(registeredPhone);
                var user = await cli.MakeAuthAsync(registeredPhone, codeRequest, code);
            }

            if (cli.IsUserAuthorized() == true)
            {
                Logger.Info("Successful autorization");
                return cli;
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error("Authorization failed");
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Telegram Client Auth exception: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when I call constructor from another class function InitializeAndAuthenticateClient hangs on on call

```
                await cli.ConnectAsync();
```

From the other hand, if I call this function inside any other function of the class TelegramBridge it works normally. Can anybody explain me where is my mistake?

Comment: You could try changing `await cli.ConnectAsync();` to `cli.Connect().ConfigureAwait(false);`, based on [this discussion](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/132).

Comment: It doesn't work because TelecramClient hasn't function Connect